# Creating tables within an HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html-table

I have a project where I need to save an html table element as an image.  It would appear that the best way to do this is to convert the data from the table into a canvas and then call toDataURL to get an image.  After searching through a lot of the tables mentioned [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/30-amazing-jquery-tables/) it looks like all of them just put a wrapper around a regular html table to make it look fancier.

1. Are there any simple way or library (this isn't fancy) to draw data in a tabular format within a canvas element?
2. Is there another way that I am missing to save the contents of a table element to an image?

Since this is a Rails project I would prefer if the JS library used JQuery.

EDIT

I forgot to mention that some of the entries in the table are links.  Obviously this works well in a regular html table, but it also needs to work in the canvas version.

EDIT 2

Apparently I wasn't clear in the first edit.  The version that's displayed to the user (be it table or canvas) needs to have links.  The final image, obviously, will not.

Comment: Jon, just a question to clarify: Is your server (php/iis) generating the data that's creating the html table?  If so, you might consider a php or iis server plugin to express the data as a pdf.

Comment: An interesting proposition, if the canvas rendering doesn't work then I'll try it.  I'm using Rails so I'm actually inserting the data directly into the DOM with ERB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example (modified from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)

http://jsfiddle.net/StEcW/1/

```
$(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
        "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" + $("#mytable").html() +
        "</foreignObject>" +
        "</svg>";
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var img = new Image();
    var svg = new Blob([data], {
        type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
    });
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
    img.src = url;
});

<div id="mytable">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style='font-size:12px'>      
        <table border=1 id="amytable">
            <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td>There</td>
            </tr>        
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works pretty well, but see the fiddle for some weirdness around possible CSS that might not work quite right. At least, in Chrome, for me, the table border didn't display the same way.

*Edit*: of course, it doesn't actually make much sense to go through canvas. The canvas is just drawing the image we've already created. All you need to do is show the image in the DOM.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work in my situation, as some entries in the table need to be links.  I tried adding an a href to the fiddle and it didn't render correctly on the canvas.  I've updated my question to add this fact.

Comment: Huh? You said, "...I need to save an html table element as an image." If you're saving it as an IMAGE, how are you planning on having the hyperlinks work...with an image?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being specific enough.  The table when displayed needs to have links.  The image does not.  I was assuming that I would just display the canvas to the user, but I guess I don't have to.  I can just convert to a canvas and then convert to an image and save that, and display the original table to the user.  Do you think that will work?

Comment: That's what I assumed you would do. I think it will work.

Comment: One cross browser issue -- I believe Internet Explorer does not support svg's <foreignobject>.

Comment: @markE Alas, it does not.  Looks like I'm writing my own level-level routines.